# Django JSONField store timetable data and query only open businesses

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

Hi in my Django backend I need to store business's timetable and I do it through a JSONField like the example below:

```
[
   {
      "times":[
         [
            "7:00",
            "9:00"
         ],
         [
            "",
            ""
         ]
      ],
      "closed":false
   },
   {
      "times":[
         [
            "7:00",
            "9:00"
         ],
         [
            "",
            ""
         ]
      ],
      "closed":false
   },
   {
      "times":[
         [
            "7:00",
            "9:00"
         ],
         [
            "",
            ""
         ]
      ],
      "closed":false
   },
   ...
]
```

Then I need to create a query to get all the opened businesses in a corresponding user_time at a day of current_day_index.

How can I index the json, for example index = 0 => "Monday", to select the timetable for that specific day and then compare the user_time with the elements in the array "times" and check if the business is open or not?

I have found this repository to do the work, but it's out of date:

> https://django-postgres-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json.html

Are there better solutions to achieve this behaviour to store timetable data?
Thank you

Comment: The question is clear

Comment: I'm asking the question because I'm not able to create the query. I have found something that can solve my questions, but it's out of date, check out: https://django-postgres-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json.html. Thank you